# Bounding box augmentation with Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: keras, object-detection

I'm using Keras to train a model to detect objects in images and put a bounding box around them.

I want to use ImageDataGenerator to augment the images with shift/rotate/sclae/etc.

The ImageDataGenerator is building a transformation matrix and using it to transform the images.

My question is, after I get back the augmented image, how can I adjust the bounding box according to the augmentation?

I'd say that if the transformation matrix was returned from the ImageDataGenerator together with the augmented image it will be great. but it doesn't.

So how to do it correctly?

Is it worth opening an issue for Keras to add this functionality?

Comment: That's a great question and I think it would be great to have some "target augmentation callback" for the automatic generators. Meanwhile, you can create your own generators. Using `cv2` perspective and affine transformations would give you that freedom.

Comment: Or just copy the code from the ImageDataGenerator :) (it's using SciPy instead of OpenCV)

Comment: Good option too :) -- Although (it might depend on your OS, I think) OpenCV is incredibly faster for me.

Comment: https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_bounding_boxes.html This should be helpful.

Comment: I was about to comment that bounding box is just an example and that it doesn't support single points. But actually is does: https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_keypoints.html